# Using a variable with Twig include

Tags: templating, include

I am trying to use a variable, based on an entry field, to load a form with a Twig include. The code is pretty straightforward:

```
{% set theForm = entry.formSelect %}
{% include theForm %}
```

Doing this throws this error:

> Undefined property: Craft\SingleOptionFieldData::$cacheKey

If I print the variable, it looks exactly as you would expect, e.g. forms/_basic

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: maybe try `entry.formSelect.value`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to let Twig interpret the variable as a string. This works for me:

```
{% set theForm = entry.formSelect %}
{% include ''~theForm~'' %}
```

Hope this helps!